# loop right in the list | python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, shortcut

well, I am trying to understand a code of some one and the point being that he used (I guess) a lot of shortcuts in his code, I can't really understand what he is trying to do and how does it work.
here is the piece of code:

```
scores = [int(scores_temp) for scores_temp in 
          input().strip().split(' ')]
```

I don't understand he makes a loop in the list? and how can he define a value `(scores_temp)` and just then create it in the for `loop`.

I really don't understands what's going on and how can I read this properly

Comment: It's called list comprehension, as Alexander has noted. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google **python list comprehension** and you'll get tons of material related to this. Looking at the given code, I guess the input is something like `"   1 2 3 4 5  "`. What you're doing inside the `[]` here is running a `for` loop and use the loop variable to create a list in one simple line

Let's break down the code. Say the input is `"   1 2 3 4 5  "`

```
input().strip()  # Strips leading and trailing spaces
>>> "1 2 3 4 5"

input().strip().split()  # Splits the string by spaces and creates a list
>>> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Now the for loop;

```
for scores_temp in input().strip().split(' ')
```

This is now equal to

```
for scores_temp in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Now the `scores_temp` will  be equal to `"1", "2", "3"...` at the each loop iteration. You want to use the variable `scores_temp` to create a loop, normally you would do,

```
scores = []
for scores_temp in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:
    scores.append(int(scores_temp))  # Convert the number string to an int
```

Instead of the 3 lines above, in python you can use list comprehension to do this in one single line. That is what `[int(scores_temp) for scores_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]`.

This is a very powerful tool in python. You can even use if conditions, more for loops ...etc inside `[]`

E.g. List of even numbers up to 10

```
[i for i in range(10) if i%2==0]
>>> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Flattening a list of lists

```
[k for j in [[1,2], [3,4]] for k in j]
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: When you get familiar with python **dictionaries** and **generators**, you can use  similar syntax with them as well. Not only lists

Answer (score 2):

This is called a `list comprehension`. It is a shortcut for creating a list.
It is the same as this code:

```
result = []
for scores_tempo in input().strip().split():
    result.append(int(scores_temp)
```

Because you need to create list, dicts, sets etc. quite often python has a special shortcut syntax for this. Also known as *syntactic sugar*.